# ExtJS 6. Adding column to grid

Tags: extjs, grid, sencha-architect, gridpanel

I want to add additional column to grid dynamically on table instantiation.
So, I've added **process**  function to gridPanel with following section

```
   var clmn = {
                xtype: 'checkcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'test,
                editor: {
                    xtype: 'checkboxfield'
                }
            };
   config.columns.push(clmn);
```

As you can see, [rowediting](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/examples/classic/grid/row-editing.html) plugin is used here too.

Actually column is added and displayed on screen. But it is not hold correct data that has been loaded, only defaultValue from model.

On row modification (when rowediting plugin is started) real data is displayed.

What is the issue here? May be there is some refresh method that should be used to refresh metadata or sth like this..

*Please, take into consideration that i am working via Sencha Architect*

Comment: I have listener on load event  for strore to process records and add some additional fields. And actually there is problem only with such fields

Answer (score 1):

columns.push() is not proper way to do this. So you should use reconfigure method which is mentioned [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure). If your store is already have fields for new columns you don't have to pass it again. Just get your current columns and add your new columns and reconfigure the grid.

edit for answer : Your problem easer than before. you can just pass your columns to it like below;

```
var yourGenericColumns = [
                     {text: 'First Name',  dataIndex:'firstname'},
                    {text: 'Last Name',  dataIndex:'lastname'}];

yourGenericColumns.push({text : 'Age', dataIndex: 'age'});

Ext.create('YourApp.YourCustomGrid',{
     columns : yourGenericColumns
});
```

Comment: this works if  instance of grid already exists. in my case columns added in process configuration, i.e before constuctor